# Daylight Saving in Primefaces chart (jqplot charts)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, charts, jqplot, dst

I am using primefaces charts to draw line chart with date axis. I am making model on server side and setting this in `<p:chart>` tag. On opening the page on any machine, it picks up the timezone of that machine and on the day when day light saving is happening. it doubles that date on x-axis. Is there any way to turn it off?

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{chartBean.graphModel}"/>
```

[image]

Comment: can you add xhtml, mb and screenshot if possible, please?

Comment: Standard times i.e. those three-latter abbreviations like CST, EST, IST etc never observe daylight saving time. How do you set these dates to the chart while displaying them on the chart (those dates should thus not be set using a standard time format (e.g. don't do this : `TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST")` instead use a time zone id `TimeZone.getTimeZone("asia/kolkata")` as per the time zone needed))? (Disclaimer : I have not yet used dates in charts). Does the time zone where the server is running on support daylight saving time? Not all time zones support DST and it may vary as time goes by.

Comment: @Tiny I am setting date as string, because this is the requirement of these charts that date is set in string format. Also if the graph has no values then its still showing DST date double. so I think Time zone ids do not matter. 
Server supports daylight saving but its not effecting the graph, client's time zone is effecting the graph

Comment: Since I have not yet used this type of charts, I unable to explain any further. As per [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/date.xhtml) showcase example, PrimeFaces merely sets dates as strings exactly as you stated i.e. without interpreting them as dates. As such, no server side APIs like `Date`, `Calendar` or whatever which PrimeFaces is supposed to use should come to play internally. If PrimeFaces renders them as strings only without interpreting them as dates, then only the client (JavaScript) should have something to do with this phenomenon which I do not know in this case.

Comment: The `set()` method takes `Object` as its first parameter, `LineChartSeries#set(Object x, Number y)`. Something could be done, if that method  is supposed to handle an instance of date / time APIs such as `Date`, `Calendar`, `DateTime` (Java 8 / Joda Time) etc with an appropriate zone of your choice.

Comment: I've no experience with the specific APIs you're using, but in general - Make sure you understand how DST works.  Read [the DST tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info), and take a close look at the graphs.  If you're talking about a fall-back transition, then local times will indeed be repeated.  In your graph, you'll have to make some decisions.  Options include 1) graph by UTC time, 2) graph by local time and show the hour repeated on the axis, 3) graph by local time and collapse the repeated time by summation, or 4) graph by local time and collapse the repeated time by averaging.

Comment: It has nothing to do with my code, the error is in the jqplot API. if there is any fix then please tell me

Comment: From http://www.zsoltnagy.eu/handling-time-in-javascript-inspired-by-the-bug-report-of-the-century/: (found using google) _"In addition, some charting libraries like an old version of jqPlot may duplicate the hour, day or month when daylight saving starts, and skip a month when daylight saving ends in case you apply the timezone offset in the wrong way. The exact opposite happens on the other half of the globe"_ So might be wort to try the latest PF version

Comment: @Kukeltje I am using PF version 5.2. its not too old

Comment: Good luck then… (did you also read BalusC comment? He always tries the latest version afaik)

Comment: i recommand to take a look to http://www.highcharts.com/ who is really better than primefaces chart ui.